# why the compiler gives warning as well as error for same mistake?

Tags: scala

In the following code, I am matching `p1` with `Person` (which would match) and `String` which wouldn't match. Why does the compiler give both warning as well as error? Why doesn't it just give one of them?

```
scala> case class Person(fname:String, lname:String, age:Int)
defined class Person

scala> val p1 = Person("manu","chadha",37)
p1: Person = Person(manu,chadha,37)
scala> p1 match {
     | case p:Person =>println(s"${p.fname},${p.lname},${p.age}");
     | case s:String =>println(s) //I know this will not match
     | }
<console>:17: warning: fruitless type test: a value of type Person cannot also be a String (the underlying of String)
       case s:String =>println(s)
              ^
<console>:17: error: pattern type is incompatible with expected type;
 found   : String
 required: Person
       case s:String =>println(s)
              ^
```

Why does this work though?

```
scala> p1 match {
     | case p:Person =>println(s"${p.fname},${p.lname},${p.age}");
     | case _ => println("something else")
     | }
manu,chadha,37
```

Comment: To make things even more interesting, if you try to pattern match a string but have the two cases from your first match, you only get an error and not a warning.

Comment: Because a `_` will match any other type constructor from the type `Person`. As it's the only case, the `_` is redundant. The `_` is not supposed to match different types, but instances (case classes) of the same type.

Comment: I think it's just being lazy in not warning unreachable code in the last case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.`fruitless type test` warning is thrown by a **checker**, see: [CheckabilityChecker](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/07d61ecf134dbba143531f5a1bd3c1289c437296/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/typechecker/Checkable.scala#L326), the **checker** just **warning** possible issue. **so why just warning?** see the below example:

```
val res = Some(1).isInstanceOf[String] // Warning:fruitless type test: a value of type Some[Int] cannot also be a String (the underlying of String)
```

the `res` will always be `false`, but it's still **legal syntax**, so the compiler will just throw **warning** for this scenario.

2.`error: pattern type is incompatible...` is thrown by type [Infer](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/27ae5f3a047d186740ac7df57f919ff9d025a625/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/typechecker/Infer.scala#L1221), In your example, it must be an error because `Person` cannot be `String` type, so this type infer error will be thrown.

Comment: That was a good one. Normally, you don't see two messages for the same position, but in this case the warning comes first, and the higher-priority error is emitted after that. That checker knows it's in a pattern, so it could fruitfully suppress that one warning. `String (the underlying of String)` is also a good one.